# Why does my <a> tag not work in <button> tag?

Tags: html

This is my code (for example) and a tag dose not work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> index </title> 
 </head>
 <body>   
  <button><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">stack</a></button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? I copied your code, opened it in Chrome, and when I clicked the button I navigated to SO.

Comment: I opened it in Firefox then I clicked the button then nothing any happened.

Comment: What is the the reason of wrapping the two elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn it around: Wrap the button in the `a` tag instead:

```html
 <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><button>stack</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it around like

```
<a href=“link.com”><button><\button><\a>
```

Or there is an easy alternative

```
 <form action="http://link.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Link”/>
</form>
```